# Browser does not suppport d3d11 with webgl

Tags: webgl, directx-11

I have both Firefox and Chrome and would want to know the probable reasons why my browser will not use d3d11.

Current Output of webGL from Firefox:

```
Platform:   Win32
Browser User Agent:     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
Context Name:   webgl2
GL Version:     WebGL 2.0
Shading Language Version:   WebGL GLSL ES 3.00
Vendor:     Mozilla
Renderer:   Mozilla
Unmasked Vendor:    Google Inc.
Unmasked Renderer:  ANGLE (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0)
Antialiasing:   Available
ANGLE:  Yes, D3D9
Major Performance Caveat:   No
```

I have even tried to force the setting in about:config

```
webgl.angle.force-d3d11 -> true
```

Comment: It is using DirectX 11 according to `ANGLE (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0)`

Comment: I don't think so. This is the more relevant line ANGLE:  Yes, D3D9

Comment: It's not relevant. It shows WebGL2, [WebGL2 on ANGLE requires DirectX 11](https://github.com/google/angle) so the fact that WebGL2 is supported at all pretty much means you're getting DirectX 11 support.